# Eclipse refresh workspace after running external tool

Tags: eclipse, coffeescript

I am sitting on a problem of that I am afraid I am not able to solve without your support and so far I haven't found any information to solve it.

### What I want

In Eclipse I want to have something like the "Java Application" launch configuration (build the application then run it) for CoffeeScript in a Node.js environment.

### What I have

I have a launch configuration which uses the coffee compiler to generate the Javascript resources and a launch configuration to start the generated Javascript in Node.js. The automatisation (first compiling then running) do I realize with a launch group in which I first run the compile configuration, wait until the compile process terminates and then try to run the Javascript in Node.js. 
[The configuration of the launch group](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w1QUU.png)

### What is the problem?

The problem is, that the Node.js configuration can't find the Javascript resources of the compile configuration. I think that this is caused by Eclipses way of storing resources. Is there any way to enforce a refresh of the workspace within a launch configuration ?

I am using Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers with the [Nodeclipse CoffeeScript Viewer (Editor before Eclipse 4.3.1)](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/nodeclipse-coffeescript-viewer-editor-eclipse-431) plugin.

- Eclipse Version: 2018-09 (4.9.0)
- Eclipse Build id: 20180917-1800

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The individual Launch Configuration for your 'compile coffeescript' launch should have a 'Refresh' tab where you can select 'Refresh resources upon completion'. Once this is selected you can choose which resources to refresh.

Comment: Thank you. I don't know how I could overlook that tab.